# Get the last created Opportunity Record with Flow or Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, process-automation

I will like to get the last Opportunity that was created. I created two custom fields on Opportunity Object:  Checkbox Field = "My Last Opportunity" and Text Field = "Last Opp ID". The idea is to set "My Last Opportunity" to True on the new created Opportunity and save his ID in "Last Opp ID" in one action. In oder action, I set the "My Last Opportunity" to false. I don't know if it's the best approch of this Use Case. Please I need your help and ideas because I did is not working. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last opportunity created you can build and autolaunched flow with a get element that quieries the first Opportunity record sorted descending created date field (this is a system field that is already available). If you want to display the result on screen build a screen flow and do the same.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank for your idea. I did it with the Autolaunched Flow and it worked. I tried also with Screen Flow and was able to get also the name. Thank you very much

Comment: You are most welcome. If you want to build flow skills search for my Youtube channel Salesforce Break. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be difficult (or impossible?) to do that in a Process Builder without code. But you can do this in a Flow if your comfortable with them. Before saving your new Opportunity, retrieve the opportunity with the field "My Last Opportunity" = true to mark the field as false. Then make your move on the new Opportunity.

Comment: Hi Clement, I did it but with After save Flow. In the Flow I used a Get Element, one Decision Element and two Update Elements and it worked,